# RabbitMQ: Delete a queue if consumer is gone forever?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

Imagine each user has it's own queue. Messages are put in to the queue when the user is offline and when they reconnect, they receive all those messages.

However, what if the client leaves and never comes back (stops using the service)? Does RabbitMQ have a way to delete a queue if messages haven't been consumed in a while? Messages might be coming in, but they aren't going out because the client is no longer active. How could I handle this with the amqp.node plugin?

Comment: This may be too late but one can set [`Queue TTL x-expires`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#queue-ttl) for this use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Imagine each user has it's own queue. Messages are put in to the queue when the user is offline and when they reconnect, they receive all those messages.

this is a common idea, but [one with unfortunate consequences, that you should avoid](http://derickbailey.com/2015/09/21/how-to-do-user-notifications-from-rabbitmq-messages/).

as i wrote in that linked article:

> You could potentially work around this by having a queue per user. You
>   could set up your code so that the web server only subscribes to a
>   queue for the user when that user is logged in and available.
>
> This doesn’t solve the problem.
>
> Now you have 30,000 messages distributed across 1,000 queues – a bad
>   situation in itself. This requires RabbitMQ to persist the queues and
>   the messages within the queues. And what happens when all 1,000 users
>   log in to your system at the same time? Now your web server has 1,000
>   queue subscriptions to deal with.

sure, you could argue that you won't have that many users. but it gets worse. in your situation, you won't be able to delete the queue the way you want, automatically.

you can set a queue to automatically delete once all consumers are disconnected. but keeping the queue around would require a consumer per user queue, where the consumer is connected for as long as that user exists. if the application crashes, the queue and all of it's messages would disappear.

TTL will only do part of what you want. it will put a life on the message in the queue and the message will be removed after that timeout... but it won't delete the queue.

ultimately, you don't want to do this with RabbitMQ.

again, from [my article on the subject](http://derickbailey.com/2015/09/21/how-to-do-user-notifications-from-rabbitmq-messages/):

> Getting back to the original scenario, what should you do when the
>   user is not online and you can’t send the message to them immediately?
>
> Store the message in a database.
>
> Add a field to the database record that says who this message belongs
>   to. When the user reconnects later, query the database for any
>   messages that this user needs to see and send them along at that time.
>
> The full process started above, then becomes this:
>
> - User’s browser connects to SignalR/Socket.io/Pusher/websockets on web
>     server
> - Web server checks a queue for updates that happen during a long
>     running process
> - When a message for a logged in user comes in
>
>   - If the
>       user is logged in, broadcast the message through the websocket to the
>       user
>   - If the user is not logged in, store the message in a database
> - When the user logs in again, query the database and send all waiting
>     messages
>
> It’s what you would have done before the idea of a message
>   queue came in to play, right? It should be what you would do now that
>   you have a message queue, as well.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, but it answers the question of "How should I approach what I want to do?" So I accepted it. You're right! I originally used a database to store these messages, but found RabbitMQ and thought of it as almost a "database of messages" of sorts which was incorrect. Thanks for opening my eyes! Quick question though... what is your recommendation for a database that stores this information?

Comment: yeah, i was hoping answering the intention and not the actual question would be more valuable :D as for what database to use? what do you normally use? what database do you already have in your app / system? stick with what you know for a database.

Comment: I think we are going to go with Redis lists. The O(1) insertion and "pop" feature is great. I'm thinking about popping values out of the redis list and sending the messages via web sockets. I'm looking for a "pop all" feature but "while pop returns not null" is another option.

Answer (score -2):

It appears to be possible, but I haven't tried it myself. See:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html

Look at Queue TTL way down at the bottom. "This controls for how long a queue can be unused before it is automatically deleted."

To see an example usage, this test in the node-amqp code base might be inspirational:

https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp/blob/f64704d3727266230901598e2daf0fa780766feb/test/test-queue-args.js#L8